# mysql_select_db not working on localhost

Tags: php, mysqli

I have installed wamp server and am working on localhost.I am trying to connect database with following code

```
 <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database ="weddingapp";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_select_db("$database", $conn);
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Connected successfully is coming along with error

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp\www\Wedding-app\config.php on line 13

I am new to PHP help me in this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli` all together. You should use `mysqli_*` only.

Comment: it's not 2002 any more. Please consider using PDO::

Comment: of swap the arguments mysql_select_db($conn,'database')

Comment: Since the error message and your code doesn't match you don't show us your real code here!

Comment: @Testing I already tried with mysqli still this error

Comment: change mysqli_select_db("$database", $conn); to mysqli_select_db($conn, $database );

Comment: You have to give user_name as "root" too

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly showing an error

```
mysql_select_db("$database", $conn);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It must be

```
mysql_select_db($conn,$database);
```

Try to learn the function

```
mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

> SideNote: You were using deprecated **mysql** version start using **mysqli** or **PDO**

Comment: Glad to help. But before asking question try to google it or check what's wrong with your code. You can learn it from [PHP.NET/MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Developer wants to choose (decice) database later on..

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving user name, change to
`$username = "root";`

Answer (score -3):

try with this

**Code:-**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database ="weddingapp";
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Mistake is you have given "$database" in line num:13 remove.

Comment: Did you check your code before posting as answer?